# How can I "cartoonize" my pictures?

Tags: photos, photo-editing

I have friends that have "cartoonized" their profile picture on social networks. How can I do that too?

I have only very elementary knowledge of graphics ([Microsoft Paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Paint)).

Comment: Have you asked your friends how they did theirs -- perhaps they could help you to do yours?

Answer (score 14):

[Cartoonize Your Photos and Videos](http://www.befunky.com/)

Answer (score 10):

Here's about 20 sites:

http://cartoonized.net/cartoonme.php

http://kusocartoon.com/photo-to-cartoon.php

from: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/11-sites-to-create-cartoon-characters-of-yourself/

1. http://illustmaker.abi-station.com/index_en.shtml
2. http://www.weeworld.com/
3. http://www.meez.com/
4. http://simpsonizeme.com/
5. http://avatars.yahoo.com/
6. http://www.befunky.com/
7. http://www.buscarmessenger.com/avatars.swf
8. http://www.cartoonme.com/en/
9. http://www.joystiq.com/media/2006/10/mii.swf
10. http://www.myplay.com.tw/
11. http://www.sp-studio.de/
12. http://www.moonjee.com/
13. http://www.toonlet.com/
14. http://cartoon.msn.com.cn/
15. http://katie.blogsite.org/
16. http://www.imvu.com/
17. http://quicktoons.com
18. http://www.faceyourmanga.com/

Answer (score 6):

Are you talking about that kind of picture?

[image: cartoon picture]

I don't know what is the site to make theme, but if you specify that this is what you want, I'm sure someone knows what the site is.

[FaceYourManga](http://www.faceyourmanga.com)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try http://simpsonizeme.com/ if you're a Simpson's fan

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a more advanced graphics program than Microsoft Paint. Programs like Photoshop and [GIMP](http://gimp.org) (which is free) include plugins and filters that can modify a photo in creative ways. Unfortunately, their user interfaces can be pretty intimidating for a new user.

Answer (score 1):

If you like [Mad Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Men) you can [make your own cartoon](http://www.amctv.com/originals/madmen/madmenyourself/) Mad Men character. It is an easy Flash interface.

An example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) is a free Windows program that can do some effects, like pencil sketch. (It's also great for general image editing - resizing, cropping, working with layers, changing formats, etc.)